# Python script for retrieving installed software on Linux PC

Tags: python

Can there be a pythonic way to retrieve software installed names/versions on a Linux system?

OR there has to be different approach for different platforms such as Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, etc?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-if-package-is-installed-in-linux/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not any 'pythonic' way to do that. You can still use installed package manager's tools to search for packages.

I created code to do some of this. It currenly supports only dpkg (used in Debian and Ubuntu) and homebrew (used in Mac OS X), but it is easy to add other package managers.

```py
import re
import subprocess

PACKAGE_MANAGERS = {
    # "command": "test if package ? exists"-commnad
    "dpkg": "dpkg -s ?",
    "brew": "brew ls ?"
    # just add new package managers here
}

def find_package_manager():
    for pm in PACKAGE_MANAGERS.keys():
        if subprocess.call(["which", pm], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) == 0:
            return pm
    raise OSError("Unable to find package manager.")

def is_package_installed(name):
    return subprocess.call(PACKAGE_MANAGERS[find_package_manager()].replace("?", name)+" > /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True) == 0

def detect_package_version(name):
    if not is_package_installed(name):
        raise OSError("Unable to find package.")
    try:
        x = subprocess.check_output(name+" --version > /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    else:
        a = re.findall("\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+", x)
        if len(a) > 0:
            return a[0]
        b = re.findall("\\d+\\.\\d+", x)
        if len(b) > 0:
            return b[0]

print is_package_installed("python")
print detect_package_version("python")
```

Sorry, it's a bit kludgy.

Since nearly all programs provide `--version` switch, I am using it to detect package version. You may want to use package manager's tools to do it.

Comment: `shutil.which` does not exist in python2.